# Looking for open source anti-spam systems, any suggestions?

Tags: open-source, lamp, spam

Basically speaking, we have a forum-like systems and every one can post their demand/supply information. So we need an anti-spam system to avoid the spams like the ads, politic-sensitive, porn, etc.

Our requirements:

a) open source

b）we can tune its features as we need

c) can be deployed on LAMP systems

By the way, the system could be able to handle Chinese

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Typepad Antispam](http://antispam.typepad.com/info/developers.html). Their API is compatible with akismet, so you can test it out very easily as a service, and then if it fits your needs and you don't want to rely on a 3rd party service, you can download their core framework and run your own.